# Foreign key value is returning as an object instead of id in datatables in django

Tags: django, django-views

When i try to get the data from the database I'm getting foreign key value as object instead of value.

in Models.py

```
class UP_ROLE_MENU_MAP(models.Model):
    iRMID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    iRoleID = models.ForeignKey(UP_ROLE_MASTER,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='',db_column='iRoleID')
    iMenuID = models.ForeignKey(up_menus,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='',db_column='iMenuID')
    iStatus = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1, blank=True,null=True)
```

In Views for DataTables

```
class OrderListJson(BaseDatatableView):
    model = UP_ROLE_MENU_MAP
    columns = ['iMenuID', 'iDeleteAccess','iAddAccess','iViewAccess']
    order_columns = ['iMenuID', 'iDeleteAccess','iAddAccess','iViewAccess']
    max_display_length = 10
    def render_column(self, row, column):
        if column == 'iViewAccess':
            return ...
        else:
            return super(OrderListJson, self).render_column(row, column)
```

output: ["up_menus object (3)", "0", "1", "link"]
How can i get the value instead of object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get the id instead of the object just change your columns from

```
columns = ['iMenuID', 'iDeleteAccess','iAddAccess','iViewAccess']
```

to

```
columns = ['iMenuID_id', 'iDeleteAccess','iAddAccess','iViewAccess']
```